# Connect to specific network, disable WiFi if the network doesn't exist (My issue in the second part)

Tags: android, networking

I'm trying to add connect to specific network, I've made an Editbox, where the user enter the network he wannna connect to, after pressing done, it will save it in SharedPreference, and i will get the string and store it.

CODE DELETED, USE THE CODE IN THE ANSWER .

Comment: The second try, with the " else if", when i run the code, it won't run the first if, it will run the " else if" even if the desired network exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your initial case is successfully connecting to the network if it does exist, then you could have a Boolean and check that after the while loop to see if you need to disable the wifi. Something like:

```
    List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
    boolean connected = false;
        for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
            if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equalsIgnoreCase("\"" + DesiredSSID + "\"")) {
                Log.d("In", "In!");
                wifiManager.disconnect();
                wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
                wifiManager.reconnect();
                connected = true;
                break;
            }
    if(!connected){wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);}
```

Comment: I've set the code as you posted, And i'm getting the same problem, when the code runs, it executes the second "if" and then run the first " if " .
So, it's running the code, => it's the desired network ? => yes => executing the second if => now it's the first if.

Comment: There should only be one if statement inside of the for loop. The connected check should occur outside of the for loop after you have already iterated through all of the connections.

Comment: Stupid me, it was inside the for loop, didn't notice that, thanks bro! + & set as an answer :) .